# Excel Html Automation

Tags: html, vba, excel, userform

I have an excel sheet which has data of the employee leave applications.
This sheet gets data from a userform which is filled by an employee.
The data then gets stored in the excel sheet for the review of manager.

What i want to do is that as soon as an entry is created it should generate a report of that particular leave application which contains all the details of the leave and save it in an html format.

Also once the manager reviews the leave application he writes comments in the application which should again get updated automatically in the html file.

I want to convert to html with a specific filename so that the file can be uploaded to my webserver and can be accessed by us anywhere and at anytime!

I also use this vba code to send email to the manager as soon as the entry is made.

```html
Sub Leave_mail()

Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

'set Importance
aEmail.Importance = 2
'Set Subject
aEmail.Subject = "EMS- " & frmLeaveappl.txtname.Text & " IS REQUESTING FOR LEAVE for: " & frmLeaveappl.txtfrom.Text & "................................"
'Set Body for mail
aEmail.htmlbody = "<img src= http://i.imgur.com/sDuiBnw.jpg><br><br><br><b>LEAVE REQUEST FROM AN EMPLOYEE</b><br><br>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "<b>NAME OF EMPLOYEE: </b>" & frmLeaveappl.txtname.Text & "<br>" _
                & vbNewLine & "<b>From: </b>" & frmLeaveappl.txtfrom.Text & "<br>" _
                & vbNewLine & "<b>To: </b>" & frmLeaveappl.txtto.Text & "<br>" _
                & vbNewLine & "<b>Reason for leave: </b>" & frmLeaveappl.txtreason.Text & "<br>" _
                & vbNewLine & "<b>Application Number: </b>" & frmLeaveappl.txtapno.Text & "<br><br><br>" _
                & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "<b><font color=red>The Status for this leave is pending!</b></font>"
                
aEmail.Recipients.Add ""

'Send Mail
aEmail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: I just have to say this:  If you are saying "employee leave application" in a forum where people code applications, and leave application means something to us, you might want to be clear and say the name is: "Employee Leave Application".  I'm just saying,  it confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record a macro doing a SaveAs HTML file????????????????????

Alt + T, M, R

then Home key then Up Arrow. Stop recording.

Gee look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

```
Range("A1").Select
```

or Saving a Web Page

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Documents\Book1.htm", _
    FileFormat:=xlHtml, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```